Dropping root privileges in NodeJS doesn't seem to have an effect
I want to have root privileges on startup and drop them later. Background is a server written with NodeJS on Ubuntu 24.04 that needs to read in a private key. I followed these instructions using process.setgid() and process.setuid() and after that elevating privileges back doesn't work.
But I saw that process.env wasn't updated. It still shows user as root, but the fields SUDO_USER, SUDO_UID and SUDO_GID where added with correct values.
Curious I tried to read a root-only file after dropping privileges and it still worked. I tried reading other root-only files and it worked.
So what am I doing wrong or am I forgetting, because what's the point in dropping root privileges when I can still read root-only files.

The behavior you're encountering is a security flaw fixed in version 20.11.1 (Changelog). You should update your node version or workaround it by only running node with the environment variable UV_USE_IO_URING=0.

... and after that elevating privileges back doesn't work.

After renouncing privileges there is no mechanism to regain them.

But I saw that process.env wasn't updated. It still shows user as root, but the fields SUDO_USER, SUDO_UID and SUDO_GID where added with correct values.

I wouldn't expect using setuid and setgid to alter your environment variables. The SUDO_* variables are present because you're running your process with sudo. If you need to check your user information you can use require('os').userInfo() (docs).

Okay, I am running v18.19.1, which seems to be the current version on Ubuntu 24.04? I know renouncing privileges is not possible, that was the desired result I wanted to check. And you are probably right about it not altering environment variables, it just made it feel like nothing got actually changed which felt to be proved by the fact I could still access root files.

Okay, I am now using node version v20.18.0. This still works, I am reading in the file in with fs.readFileSync
